# Task notification

Tags: apex

When task is created and assigned to a particular person/assignee the task is visible to one person only with no option other people to see and to be notified of the existence of the task. This creates a concern in cases when the recipient is not in the office, the task may not be seen on time and handled by the person who substitutes the recipient. Is there a way to notify more than one person when task is created, for example to add an additional CC field and include more people similar to the way it is done in the mail clients - Microsoft Outlook for example?

Regards,

Dilyan

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this problem

1. You can create a new user group and post to that chatter group using Lightning Process Builder

[image: Process Builder]

2. You can use Process builder to call your apex class to send the email (You need to write the apex logic. whom you want to send? etc.)